# What is the Best way to loop over an array in scala

Tags: arrays, list, scala, tail

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to refactor the below code.I want to eliminate "index" used in the below code and loop over the array to fetch data.

```
 subgroupMetricIndividual.instances.foreach { instanceIndividual =>
   val MetricContextListBuffer: ListBuffer[Context] = ListBuffer()
   var index = 0
   contextListBufferForSubGroup.foreach { contextIndividual =>
        MetricContextListBuffer += Context(
                 entity = contextIndividual,
                 value = instanceIndividual(index).toString
        )
        index += 1
   }
}
```

For instance, if the values of variables are as below:

```
contextListBufferForSubGroup = ("context1","context2")
subgroupMetricIndividual.instances = {{"Inst1","Inst2",1},{"Inst3","Inst4",2}}
```

Then Context should be something like:

```
  { 
   entity: "context1",
   value:  "Inst1"
   },
   { 
   entity: "context2",
   value:  "Inst2"
   },
   { 
   entity: "context1",
   value:  "Inst3"
   },
   { 
   entity: "context2",
   value:  "Inst4"
   }
```

Note:

instanceIndividual can have more elements than those in contextListBufferForSubGroup. We must ignore the last extra elements in instanceIndividual in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip two lists into a list of tuples and then map over that.
e.g.

```
subgroupMetricIndividual.instances.foreach { instanceIndividual =>
  val MetricContextListBuffer = contextListBufferForSubGroup.zip(instanceIndividual).map {
    case (contextIndividual, instanceIndividualIndex) => Context(
      entity = contextIndividual,
      value = instanceIndividualIndex.toString
    )
  }
}
```

If `Context` can be called like a function i.e. `Context(contextIndividual, instanceIndividualIndex.toString)` then you can write this even shorter.

```
subgroupMetricIndividual.instances.foreach { instanceIndividual =>
  val MetricContextListBuffer = contextListBufferForSubGroup
    .zip(instanceIndividual.map(_.toString)).map(Context.tupled)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your exact datatypes, I'm mocked up something which is probably close to what you want, and is slightly more functional using maps, and immutable collections

```
case class Context(entity:String, value:String)

val contextListBufferForSubGroup = List("context1","context2")
val subgroupMetricIndividualInstances = List(List("Inst1","Inst2",1),List("Inst3","Inst4",2))

val result: List[Context] = subgroupMetricIndividualInstances.map { instanceIndividual =>
contextListBufferForSubGroup.zip(instanceIndividual) map { case v: (String, String) =>
    Context(
      entity = v._1,
      value = v._2
    )
  }
}.flatten
```